# Redirection Based on Query String

Tags: javascript, redirect, query-string, window.location

Not wanting to bloat up an .htaccess with 300 entries, what would be the javascript I could use to redirect to URLs based on a query string in the request to this single file. For example,

https://www.mywebsite.com/redirect.jhtml?Type=Cool&LinkID=57

The only part I care about is the 57 and then redirect it to wherever:
https://www.anothercoolwebsite/secretworld/

In the following case, take the 34 and redirect:

https://www.mywebsite.com/redirect.jhtml?Type=Cool&LinkID=34
https://www.anoldwebsite.com/cool/file.html

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you want to take like id?

Comment: start by looking at `window.location`. You could use a regex pattern match on this to get the param you want, like this maybe `location.match(/LinkID=([0-9]+)/)`.

Comment: Yes, I referenced this in my tag. window.location was the first thing which came to mind. I am not sure how to incorporate the query string into a defined value for a redirect though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do you fine. Keep in mind a server-side solution like a PHP script will work for more clients. Since you mentioned `.htaccess`, I think I should let you know about the [fallback resource command](https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2012/01/21/apaches-fallbackresource-your-new-htaccess-command/)

Anyways, here is the JS only solution

```
function parseString(){//Parse query string
    var queryString=location.search.substring(1);//Remove ? mark

    var pair = queryString.split('&'); //Key value pairs

    var returnVal={};
    pair.forEach(function(item,i){
        var currPair = item.split('=');//Give name and value

        returnVal[currPair[0]]=currPair[1];
    });

    return returnVal;
}

var links=["index", "about"];//Sample array of links, make sure this matches up with your LinkID
location.href=links[parseString().LinkID]+".html"; //Redirect based on LinkID
```

Comment: Thank you, Ben! I am confused on how to associate several LinkIDs with their related URLs though. How would I send 57 to https://www.anothercoolwebsite/secretworld/ and 34 to https://www.anoldwebsite.com/cool/file.html for example?

Comment: @DavidTurner In the second last line, I show an array, arrays start counting at zero, so "index" would be LinkID=0, "about" would be 1, etc etc